# jpa method to query by joined column

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I want a query something like this

```
select tm ,tb
from TrainingMaster tm 
left join TblBranchTraining tb on tm.id = tb.trainingId 
where (tb.branchCode = :branchCode OR tb.branchCode is null) ;
```

Here are my entity classes

```
public class TrainingMaster implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="training_name")
    private String trainingName;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false,name = "id",referencedColumnName = "training_id")
    private TblBranchTraining branchTraining;
}
```

And

```
public class TblBranchTraining implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "training_id")
    private Integer trainingId;
     
    
    private String status;
    
    private String date;
        
    @Column(name = "branch_code")
    private String branchCode;

}
```

And here is my Repository Method

```
@Repository
public interface TrainingMasterRepository extends JpaRepository<TrainingMaster, Integer> {

    List<TrainingMaster> findByAllTrainingMasters_branchCode(String branchCode);

}
```

but this JPA method is not generating the query what I want. which is `OR tb.branchCode is null`

I tried creating query (which is posted above) but that is giving all records which belongs to other branchCode

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do left join by using method queries, you can look at what you can do here [Spring Data JPA Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation).

If you want to use left join you can use @Query annotation something like this will work:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u FROM Post p LEFT JOIN p.user u WHERE p IS NULL");
@Query(
    "SELECT tm" +
    "FROM TrainingMaster tm" +
    "LEFT JOIN TblBranchTraining tb ON tm.id = tb.trainingId" +
    "WHERE tb.branchCode = branchCode" +
    "OR tb.branchCode IS NULL"
 List<TrainingMaster> findByAllTrainingMasters_branchCode(@Param("branchCode") String branchCode);
```

Comment: using this query I am getting data which doestnot belongs the the branchCode I am sending in parameter

Answer (score -3):

```
@Repository
public interface TrainingMasterRepository extends JpaRepository<TrainingMaster, Integer> {
  List<TrainingMaster> findAllByTblBranchTraining_branchCode(String branchCode);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on how the proposed solution solves the problem and how it helps the OP.